# Eventos distintos, una sola operación en C#

Tags: c#, poo

¿Cómo hago para que ante dos eventos diferentes (clic del ratón, presionar la tecla ENTER) se realicen las mismas operaciones?

Estoy aprendiendo C# y se me complica un poco hacerlo.

Muchas gracias por adelantado!!!

Comment: Muchas gracias @Leandro!!!

Answer (score 2):

Podrias crea una funcion comun que llames desde ambos eventos, como ser

```
public void button1_click(...)
{
    FunctionComun();
}

public void textbox1_keypress(...)
{
    if(e.KeyChar == Keys.Enter){
        FunctionComun();
    }
}

private void FunctionComun(){
  //codig
}
```

Igualmente si co presionar `enter` hacias referencia al boton recuerda que existe la propiedad

[AcceptButton](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.acceptbutton?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Forms_Form_AcceptButton)

del `Form` donde puedes indica que boton se acciona cuando presionas enter

Pero en este caso el evento es lo mismo, o sea el `click` del boton, por lo tanto no hay dos eventos, tanto con el enter o con el mouse el evento sera el click